# IOC/DI voilates interfaces definition

Tags: c#, interface, inversion-of-control

I have read about IOC/DI for dependency injection. It says to create interfaces of every class that we wish to inject. Doesn't it violates the definition of interface(implement where we want to enforce behavior in a class). Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could you cite an example, so that we can understand your point better

Comment: I'm not sure where you would have read "Create interfaces of every class", do you mean create interfaces for the classes you wish to inject?

Comment: yes. its quite obvious if i will construct a class then somewhere i will create its object.

Comment: I don't follow how creating an interface violates the definition of an interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your main point of confusion is that in a DI/IoC scenario, we don't have a *class* we want to inject, we have a *service* we want to inject. Let's say I have a `Logger` class. It's not the `Logger` class itself I want to inject, it's the set of logging services described by the `ILogger` interface. If I wasn't using DI or IoC, I would have a place in each class where I would go `ILogger _logger = new Logger()`, or maybe `ILogger _logger = Logger.Instance`, both of which couple my code to a specific instance of the `ILogger` interface. But with DI/IoC, I leave this step to the framework, and don't bother with the specific implementation in my business logic class.

Answer (score 1):

> > Doesn't it violates the definition of interface(implement where we want to enforce behavior in a class)?

No it doesn't.

The mere fact that you are creating an interface implies that you are defining behaviour.  Whether or not you are going to use DI to get to your implementation is not all that relevant.